# How to access Android XML children

Tags: android, xml

A simple defined resource file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <string name="hello_world">Hello World!<string>
   </resources>
```

Can be accessed with

```
@string/hello_world
```

But what about a child like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <item name="the_item">
            <state name="state_1">
                 <coordinates x="320" y="413" z="1000" />
            </state>
            <state name="state_2">
            ...
       <item>
   </resources>
```

What do I write to get the x value written on screen?
I would like to define this in a resource file and not normal XML with a parser. I'm searching for an answer close to

```
@item/the_item/state_1/x
```

Answer (score 0):

it's imposible, because your definition is wrong, you can't use and item in that way, and defined other kind of resources like state or coordinates, I suggest you use a dimension resource, like:

```
<dimen name="state_1_x">320px</dimen>
```

you can change the "px" for other king of dimension, like dp, sp, or other.

The items usually are used for integer or string arrays.

Comment: So you cannot have resources with multiple child nodes?

Comment: Not created or invented by you. That xml is for specific resources. Read more about them http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html